# Docker: RVM command not found

Tags: rvm, vagrant, docker

I am spinning up a VM with docker installed using Vagrant
which also installs installs RVM and Ruby 2.1:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

$rvm= <<SCRIPT
unset GEM_HOME
curl -L https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
echo "source /home/vagrant/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> .bash_history
echo 'gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc' > ~/.gemrc
rvm install 2.1.1
SCRIPT

$setup= <<SCRIPT
docker build -t campaign/development:latest /home/vagrant
#docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v /home/vagrant:/home/vagrant --name development development:latest
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"      
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = 2048
  end      
  # need a private network for NFS shares to work
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"      
  # Rails Server Port Forwarding
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant", create: true, type: "nfs"      

  # Install RVM
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $rvm

  # Install latest docker
  config.vm.provision "docker"
  config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: $setup
end
```

The build command hits the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM rails

RUN adduser web --home /home/vagrant --shell /bin/bash --disabled-password --gecos ""
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Separate Gemfile ADD so that `bundle install` can be cached more effectively
RUN chown -R web:web /home/vagrant &&\
    mkdir -p /home/vagrant/bundle &&\
    chown -R web:web /home/vagrant/bundle
ADD Gemfile      /home/vagrant/
ADD Gemfile.lock /home/vagrant/   

RUN rvm use 2.1.1@campaign --create &&\
    bundle install --development

...
```

When I get to STEP 6, the RUN rvm command returns:

```
Step 6 : RUN rvm use 2.1.1@campaign --create && bundle install --development
---> Running in 86e80ff96036
/bin/sh: rvm: command not found
INFO[0012] The command [/bin/sh -c rvm use 2.1.1@campaign 
--create &&    bundle install --development] returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I am just confused because I can ssh onto the box and run RVM commands,
and my ruby/gemset are created. Should I even be trying to run RVM commands
in the Dockerfile or should I just have an install script thats ran in the Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 3):

rvm is launched using a script installed. That script has to be added to your session, but it is not being added using directly run in you `Dockerfile`. You can try using:

```
> RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm use 2.1.1@campaign --create bundle install --development"
```

Answer (score 2):

If rvm is not found, but needs to be used inside your container, you can either add it to path via console by typing:

```
bash -l -c PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/rvm/binary
```

Or add it to your default container user's .profile or .bashrc (its in /root or under /home/username)

Comment: No, it cannot work like that with rvm, you must wrap command with "bash -l -c"

Comment: this is because Docker use ``sh`` when doing RUN instructions. A nightmare to find this out ;/